# Is there a difference between declaring a global as part of the class declaration statement and a global declared with a separate statement?

Tags: c++, global-variables

Is there a difference of how the global variables behave between these two examples? My intuition says there is no difference, but I may be wrong.

First Example:

```
class A
{
  // ...
};

A g_A;
```

Second Example:

```
class B
{
  // ...
} g_B;
```

Comment: Well, there is one less newline, one less character, and one less semicolon ;)

Comment: @NathanOliver Feeling pedantic today, are we? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's no difference in this case.

But, please try to avoid global variables.

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly on trying to avoid global variables when possible. But I am examining code written by someone else and wanted to make sure it was behaving the way I thought it was :)